# Common neighbour matrix of a graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, network, adjacency-matrix, skew-symmetric-matrices

## Problem

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a [simple graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Graph), $A$ its [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and let $c(u,v) = |N(u) \cap N(v)|$ be the number of *common neighbours* of any pair of nodes $u,v \in V$, i.e.
$$c(u,v) = \big|\big\{ w \in V : \{u,w\},\{v,w\} \in E \big\}\big| \, .$$
How can the matrix of common neighbours, $C = \big(c(u,v)_{u,v \in V}\big)$, be expressed in terms of the adjacency matrix $A$?

---

## Motivation

I'm a big fan of Linear Algebra and I a firm believer that many unobvious insights can be achieved by algebraic manipulations of the corresponding matrix representations.

#### Some examples

Here is a small collection of how important graph-theoretic properties can be expressed in terms of the adjacency matrix:

- The number [walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) of length $k$ from $u$ to $v$ is given by $p_k(u,v) = (A^k)_{uv}$.
- The number of shared triangles between two nodes can either be expressed as the number of walks of length $2$ that are also neighbours, $\Delta(G) = A^2 \odot A$, with $\odot$ denoting the [pointwise multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).
- The [degree vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of a graph can either be expressed as

  - the sum of each row/column, $\deg(G) = A\mathbf{1}$,
  - the diagonal of the squared adjacency matrix, $\deg(G) = \operatorname{diag}(A^2)$,
    i.e. the number of $2$-walks from each node to itself.
- Similarly, the number of triangles at each node (which I'd like to call *triangle degree*) is the number of $3$-walks from each node to itself, $\deg_{\Delta}(G) = \operatorname{diag}(A^3)$.

Comment: Isn't it just $A^TA$?

Comment: $A$ is symmetric, so $A^TA=A^2$, which does not describe the number of common neighbors.

Comment: Actually, it does. $(A^2)_{i,j}$ is the number of walks of length 2 between $i,j$, that is the number of common neighbors..

Comment: Oh... you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is $A^TA$, see comments above.